# Setting default columns hidden using DataTable ColVis extension

Tags: datatables

How can I provide a list of columns I want hidden on table load through the ColVis extension?

Also, is there a way to retrieve the list of columns currently visible/hidden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Specify visible columns**

You can set visibility with [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) or [`columns`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) options to target specific columns along with [`columns.visible`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) option to set column visibility.

For example, to hide a second column initially, use the following options:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': [
       { targets: 1, visible: false }
    ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4thrrdn/) for demonstration.

**Get a list of visible columns**

You can get a list of visible columns bu using [`columns().visible()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.visible%28%29) method.

```
var colVisible = table.columns().visible();
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4thrrdn/1/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

The ColVis extension gives no method to hide columns on load. That is .Datatable() job to do.

To get the list of columns which are visible/hidden you can do something like this

```
var length = myTable.columns().nodes().length,
    result = [];
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
    result.push(myTable.column(i).visible());
}
console.log(result);
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/25/**